# How to replace word in wordress post title sql database from phpmyadmi panel?

Tags: sql, wordpress, phpmyadmin

Let's say I want to replace word "one" to "two" in wordpress every post title via phpmyadmin. How to do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL (via phpMyAdmin)](//stackoverflow.com/q/46980604/90527)

Answer (score 0):

for all post titles

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_title = REPLACE (  post_title,  'text to find here',  'text to replace here');
```